# TDS Item sync issue Length of field content doesn't match the content-length attribute

Tags: tds

an attribute  `*.item -text` is already existing in the .git attributes file. Are we missing something here. This doesn't happen while syncing all the TDS files. It happens only to certain files.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TDS serialization uses the default Sitecore serialization format.
For this case all fields are [saved with content-length](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/the-default-serialization-format.html), e.g.:

```
----field----
field: {A60ACD61-A6DB-4182-8329-C957982CEC74}
name: Text
key: text
content-length: 788

[Some Value]
```

Value of `content-length` should correspond to the length of content `[Some Value]`. If the length of content in the field is different, you will get this error message. Usually, this kind of error you get when you solve `git` conflicts manually and make mistakes. You have few options:

1. Find the file that causes an error, calculate new content length, and change it to the proper value.
2. Find the file that causes an error and check `git` history on it. The most probably that you have started to get this problem after not successful merge of conflicts. Revert to the working version.
3. Find the file that causes an error. Set `content-length` of the field to 0. Set value to an empty line. Sync the item. Change the value of the field in the Sitecore Content Editor. Sync item again. And you should get proper values in the file.